# How to use admin Form in a custom page Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to use the same form for date and time used in admin page but in a custom page.

I've created a form class like this:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin import widgets as adminWidget

class RequestData(forms.Form):
    data = forms.DateField(widget=adminWidget.AdminDateWidget())
```

When I show this form in a template it doesn't look like in the admin page

Comment: Do you mean using the AdminDateWidget? B/C you are creating your own form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your template (base.html probably)

```
{% load admin_static %}
```

if doesnt work, add this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/forms.css" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/actions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/urlify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/prepopulate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/inlines.js"></script>
```